# Square wave function for Matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I'm new to programming in Matlab. I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the following function:

[image]

I know my code is off, I just wanted to start with some form of the function. I have attempted to write out the sum of the function in the program below.

```
function [g] = square_wave(n)
g = symsum(((sin((2k-1)*t))/(2k-1)), 1,n);
end
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Update:

My code as of now:

```
function [yout] = square_wave(n)
syms n;
f = n^4;
df = diff(f);
syms t k;
f = 1; %//Define frequency here
funcSum = (sin(2*pi*(2*k - 1)*f*t) / (2*k - 1));
funcOut = symsum(func, v, start, finish);
xsquare = (4/pi) * symsum(funcSum, k, 1, Inf);
tVector = 0 : 0.01 : 4*pi; %// Choose a step size of 0.01
yout = subs(xsquare, t, tVector);

end
```

Comment: Look at the duplicate I linked to.  That has already been answered.  Look at my answer specifically: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24004603/3250829

Comment: Thanks, I attempted to write out the code you posted into my own function. I need it to return as a row vector. Unfortunately I'm not having much luck.

Comment: What is given is a function with respect to `t`. If you want a vector, you need to read the end of the post. You'll see that the post defines a time vector between `[-3,3]` and then uses `subs` and with respect to the square generation function, it generates the actual time/amplitude values.  In your case, it's now `[0, 4*pi]`. Simply change the boundaries from `[-3,3]` to `[0,4*pi]` and you have your answer. Actually, you need 1001 points, and so you should have `t = linspace(0, 4*pi, 1001);`. Also, what I did was a summation up to infinity or `Inf`. All you have to do is change `Inf` to `n`.

Comment: Ok, I understand that it is a function with respect to t. So would the input from the user be t? I'm trying to set up the first line of my code, right now it is: function [yout] = square_wave(t). However, when I try to input a value, I get the following error: Error in square_wave (line 2)
syms x;

Comment: I've reopened the question and provided an answer.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** This answer was partly inspired by a previous post I wrote here: [How to have square wave in Matlab symbolic equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003548/how-to-have-square-wave-in-matlab-symbolic-equation/24004603#24004603) - However, it isn't quite the same, which is why I'm providing an answer here.

---

Alright, so it looks like you got the first bit of the question right.  However, when you're multiplying things together, you need to use the `*` operator... and so `2k - 1` should be `2*k - 1`.  Ignoring this, you are `symsum`ing correctly given that square wave equation.  The input into this function is only one parameter only - `n`.  What you see in the above equation is a [Fourier Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) representation of a square wave.  A bastardized version of this theory is that you can represent a periodic function as an infinite summation of sinusoidal functions with each function weighted by a certain amount.  What you see in the equation is in fact the Fourier Series of a square wave.

`n` controls the total number of sinusoids to add into the equation.  The more sinusoids you have, the more the function is going to look like a square wave.  In the question, they want you to play around with the value of `n`.  If `n` becomes very large, it should start approaching what looks like to be a square wave.

The `symsum` will represent this Fourier Series as a function with respect to `t`.  What you need to do now is you need to substitute values of `t` into this expression to get the output amplitude for each value `t`.  They define that for you already where it's a vector from `0` to `4*pi` with 1001 points in between.

Define this vector, then you'll need to use [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) to substitute the time values into the `symsum` expression and when you're done, cast them back to `double` so that you actually get a numeric vector.

As such, your function should simply be this:

```
function [g] = square_wave(n)

syms t k; %// Define t and k 
f = sin((2*k-1)*t)/(2*k-1); %// Define function
F = symsum(f, k, 1, n); %// Define Fourier Series
tVector = linspace(0, 4*pi, 1001); %// Define time points
g = double(subs(F, t, tVector)); %// Get numeric output

end
```

The first line defines `t` and `k` to be symbolic because `t` and `k` are symbolic in the expression.  Next, I'll define `f` to be the term inside the summation with respect to `t` and `k`.  The line after that defines the actual sum itself.  We use `f` and sum with respect to `k` as that is what the summation calls for and we sum from 1 up to `n`.  Last but not least, we define a time vector from `0` to `4*pi` with 1001 points in between and we use `subs` to substitute the value of `t` in the Fourier Series with all values in this vector.  The result should be a 1001 vector which I then cast to `double` to get a numerical result and we get your desired output.

To show you that this works, we can try this with `n = 20`.   Do this in the command prompt now:

```
>> g = square_wave(20);
>> t = linspace(0, 4*pi, 1001);
>> plot(t, g);
```

We get:

[image]

Therefore, if you make `n` go higher... so 200 as they suggest, you'll see that the wave will eventually look like what you expect from a square wave.

---

If you don't have the Symbolic Math Toolbox, which `symsum`, `syms` and `subs` relies on, we can do it completely numerically.  What you'll have to do is define a [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) of points for pairs of `t` and `n`, substitute each pair into the sequence equation for the Fourier Series and sum up all of the results.

As such, you'd do something like this:

```
function [g] = square_wave(n)

tVector = linspace(0, 4*pi, 1001); %// Define time points
[t,k] = meshgrid(tVector, 1:n); %// Define meshgrid
f = sin((2*k-1).*t)./(2*k-1); %// Define Fourier Series
g = sum(f, 1); %// Sum up for each time point

end
```

The first line of code defines our time points from `0` to `4*pi`.  The next line of code defines a `meshgrid` of points.  How this works is that for `t`, each column defines a unique time point, so the first column is 200 zeroes, up to the last column which is a column of 200 `4*pi` values.  Similarly for `k`, each **row** denotes a unique `n` value so the first row is 1001 1s, followed by 1001 2s, up to 1001 1s.  The implications with this is now each column of `t` and `k` denotes the right `(t,n)` pairs to compute the output of the Fourier series for each time that is unique to that column.

As such, you'd simply use the sequence equation and do **element-wise** multiplication and division, then sum along each individual column to finally get the square wave output.  With the above code, you will get the same result as above, and it'll be much faster than `symsum` because we're doing it numerically now and not doing it symbolically which has a lot more computational overhead.

Here's what we get when `n = 200`:

[image]

This code with `n=200` ran in milliseconds whereas the `symsum` equivalent took almost 2 minutes on my machine - Mac OS X 10.10.3 Yosemite, 16 GB RAM, Intel Core i7 2.3 GHz.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, this syntax is quite difficult for me to understand. I appreciate your patience!

Comment: @statsguyz - Oh that's no problem at all.  I figured I would just reopen and give you an answer rather than go back and forth in the comments.  Try that out and let me know how it goes!

Comment: I must be missing something. When I run the function, I get the following error: To use 'syms', you might need:
  syms - Symbolic Math Toolbox

Comment: Uh oh... yeah that's a problem.  I assumed you had the symbolic math toolbox since you used `symsum`.  If you don't have that, then what I suggested above won't work.... which doesn't make sense because it sounds like you have a fairly recent version of MATLAB.  What is your version btw?  Also, please type in `ver` into your command prompt, push ENTER, and see if the Symbolic Toolbox is there as part of the list of toolboxes available to you.

Comment: MATLAB Version: 8.5.0.197613 (R2015a)

Comment: @statsguyz - Much more recent than the one I have.  Is the Symbolic Math Toolbox available to you?

Comment: I am using a student version for a course I am taking. I'm checking to see if it is available.

Comment: @statsguyz Type in `ver`, push ENTER, and scroll down and look to see if the Symbolic Math Toolbox is listed as part of your toolbox availability.  If you don't have it, then we can still what you want, but it will take a bit more work.

Comment: I am in the process of downloading it now.

Comment: @statsguyz - Sounds good.  Download it, install it, then run the code and see if it works.  Let me know!

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to access the Symbolic Math Toolbox.

Comment: @statsguyz - We'll have to do it numerically.  I'll modify my answer.

Comment: @statsguyz - Done.  Have a look.

Comment: It works! I need to go through each line and really understand it. I appreciate all of your help.

Comment: @statsguyz No worries. Please consider accepting my answer if you no longer need help. Thanks!