# Series of rectangular pulses with increasing pulse length in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to define a function which is a series of rectangular pulses, where the length of a pulse increases by a constant with each repeat. The distance between the pulses should remain the same.
How would I do this in MATLAB?

[image]
In the Sketch d is the gap between the pulses, a is the starting pulse length, and l is the constant by which the length increases.

Comment: if you show what you tried, that would be helpful

Comment: Distance as in the centre of the pulse to the neighbouring pulse's centre or the gap (duty-off) period? Code attempts are appreciated. I appreciate a good diagram if anything else cannot be provided.

Comment: I have very little experience in Matlab and tbh I'm not even sure where to start. So unfortunately I can't provide my attempts yet. I think it should be based around a pulse train 'y = pulstran(t,d,func)', but I'm not sure how to set the parameters so that they change with each pulse. I have edited my question and attached a sketch of the function.

Comment: @pythonics1 Thanks for the diagram a lot more clarity was gained from that. Couldn't figure out how to use the `pulstran(t,d,func)` yet but an iterative approach might interest you.

Comment: related question.... https://stackoverflow.com/a/24004425/1292464

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Iteratively Concatenating Pulses to Generate Variable Pulse Train

The method below uses an iterative approach to create a pulse train signal. On each iteration, a cycle of the signal is concatenated to an array name `Full_Signal` in this case. `Full_Signal` will store the entire signal that is to be plotted. A cycle in this context is considered to be the high pulse `a+l` followed by an off-state `d`. The sizing and properties of the signal can be adjusted by using the variables `a`,`l`,`d`,`Max_Time` and `Number_Of_Cycles`. Some things to note is `ones(m,n)` creates an array of ones with `m` rows and `n` columns. Similiar `zeros(m,n)` follows the same structure and generates an array of zeros. Parameters `a`,`l` and `d` will be proportional to the time vector specifications.

[image: Variable Pulse Train Plot]

```
%Clearing the workspace%
clear;
clc;
clf;

%*********************************************************%
%ADJUSTABLE PARAMETERS%
%*********************************************************%
a = 15;
l = 1;
d = 40;
Max_Time = 100;
Number_Of_Cycles = 10;
%*********************************************************%

%Will hold the entire signal%
Full_Signal = [];

%Interatively concatenating cycles%
Cycle = 1;
while(Cycle < Number_Of_Cycles)

    Duty_High = a + Cycle*(Cycle - 1);
    Signal_Portion = [ones(1,Duty_High) zeros(1,d)];
    Full_Signal = [Full_Signal Signal_Portion];
    Cycle = Cycle + 1;

end

%Creating time scale/x-axis%
t = linspace(0,Max_Time,length(Full_Signal));

%Plotting the signal%
figure('Position', [300 400 500 100])
plot(t,Full_Signal);
axis([0 Max_Time 0 1.1]);
title("Variable Pulse Train");
xlabel("Time"); ylabel("Amplitude");
```

### Extension: Using Interpolation to Set the Plotting Density and Units Scaled to the Time Axis

Alternatively, if you wish to have the variable `a`,`l` and `d` be in units of time then interpolation can be used to set the Plotting_Density and retain a pretty clear plot. Interpolation using the function `interp1` to create allows you to create a time vector of varying precision and map the signal to this new interpolated time vector accordingly.

[image: Interpolated Result]

```
%Clearing the workspace%
clear;
clc;
clf;

%*********************************************************%
%ADJUSTABLE PARAMETERS%
%*********************************************************%
a = 15;
l = 1;
d = 40;
Max_Time = 1000;
Number_Of_Cycles = 10;
Plotting_Density = 0.0001;
%*********************************************************%

Number_Of_Cycles = Number_Of_Cycles + 1;
%Will hold the entire signal%
Full_Signal = [];

%Interatively concatenating cycles%
Cycle = 1;
while(Cycle < Number_Of_Cycles)

    Duty_High = a + Cycle*(Cycle - 1);
    Signal_Portion = [ones(1,Duty_High) zeros(1,d)];
    Full_Signal = [Full_Signal Signal_Portion];
    Cycle = Cycle + 1;

end

%Creating time scale/x-axis%
t = (0:1:length(Full_Signal)-1);
Interpolated_Time_Vector = (0:Plotting_Density:length(Full_Signal)-1);
Interpolated_Signal = interp1(t,Full_Signal,Interpolated_Time_Vector);

close all;
%Plotting the signal%
figure('Position', [300 400 500 100])
plot(Interpolated_Time_Vector,Interpolated_Signal);
axis([0 max(Interpolated_Time_Vector) 0 1.1]);
title("Variable Pulse Train");
xlabel("Time (s)"); ylabel("Amplitude");
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Thank you, that looks really good. One question, how do the parameters a, d, l, translate to the plot? Because d = 40, but in the plot it looks to be around 5

Comment: @pythonics1 If you would like the plot to be proportional to time you can set the maximum time to be the same length as the Full_Signal. Right now the sizes are proportional to how many time units are present.

Comment: @pythonics1 I have now added interpolation and the time is now scaled accordingly.